# Javascript outputting a new div but not responding with firebase server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pull up a chat overlay comes over the current html, everything works besides the fact that my firebase content is not loading. It might have something to do with the output = output parts. Do you think it may be that my id cannot be defined. So the overlay does come up and shows all the divs, except the actual content that is supposed to be in my #messageDiv.

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://tbfnchatnew.firebaseio.com/');
 $('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var name = $('#nameInput').val();
      var text = $('#messageInput').val();

      var names = "joe","Joe"];
      var bad_name = false;

      for (var k in names) {
        var this_name = names[k];
        if(name.indexOf(this_name) > -1) {
          bad_name = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (bad_name) {
        alert('That is the Bosses name silly!');
        e.off();
      }

      if (text == "") {
        alert("Please do not give us RBF, Input your message");
        e.off();
      }
      myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
      $('#messageInput').val('');      
    }
});
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    displayChatMessage(message.name, message.text);
});
function displayChatMessage(name, text) {
    $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<em/>').text(name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
    $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
};

$("#chat-answer").delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
var getTextf = function(){
dialogInput.set('textAnswerf', "Chat")
};

var dialogInput = {
id: null,
value: null,
set: function(resultID, question){
dialogInput.id = resultID;
var output = "";

output = output + "<h3>Chat</h3>";
output = output + "<div id='messagesDiv' class='chat-wrapper'></div>";
output = output + "<div id='chat-answer'><input type='text' id='nameInput' class='chat-input-name chat-input' placeholder='Name'><textarea type='text' id='messageInput' class='chat-input-mess chat-input' placeholder='Message' required=''></textarea></div>";

output = output + "<a href='javascript:dialogInput.cancel()' class='input-click'> Cancel </a>";
document.getElementById("overlay").innerHTML = output;
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
},
hide: function(){   

document.getElementById("overlay").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
},
done: function(){
document.getElementById(dialogInput.id).innerHTML =  document.getElementById("overlay").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

},
cancel: function(){

dialogInput.hide();
}
}
```

html: this calls the actual overlay + the div overlay

```
<a href='javascript:getTextf()' class="link-click" style="z-index:100;"><img src="../images/chat.png" class="menu-image"></a>
<div id='overlay' style="z-index:1000;"></div>
```

Also the script is in my head not in the footer but I have tried moving to different locations and it still does not load.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? I noticed near the top of your script you're missing the initial bracket here: `var names = "joe","Joe"];`

Comment: @JesseKernaghan hey acutally I found this to be very complicated and unclean i decided to implement this into a better jquery/bootstrap function. Thank you for the help tho. pls